# How to display another div when clicked on a div using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I want to use CSS only to show a div when clicked on another div

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="contentmenu">
                <div class="show">
                    <a class="show">
                        My Student
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a><br/>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a><br/>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a><br/>
                </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code is

```
#contentmenu{
    margin-top: 79px;
    background-color: #E9D4B5;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}
.show{
    margin-top: 2%;
    background-color: #CE9127;
    width: 96%;
    height: 10%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
    padding-left: 8%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

So how to display div (class = hidden) when clicked on the div (class = show) using CSS only

Comment: this is not possible with just css

Comment: alternatively, it is possible using javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/3sG7Z/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with the [Checkbox Hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), though be sure to make sure browser support is sufficient. It would look like this:

```
#contentmenu{
    margin-top: 79px;
    background-color: #E9D4B5;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}
.show{
    margin-top: 2%;
    background-color: #CE9127;
    width: 96%;
    height: 10%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
    padding-left: 8%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hidden {
   display: block;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<div id="contentmenu">
    <label for="toggle-1"><a class="show">
      My Student
      </a></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
  <div class="hidden">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/exuvez/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

For no hacks, and no javascript you can achieve what you want with a hover event. Just a small change and addition to the css:

```
#contentmenu{
    margin-top: 79px;
    background-color: #E9D4B5;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}
.show{
    margin-top: 2%;
    background-color: #CE9127;
    width: 96%;
    height: 10%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
    padding-left: 8%;
    margin-top: 1%;
  width:100%;
}

.show:hover + .hidden {
  display:block;
}
.hidden:hover {
 display:block; 
}
```

So width:100% has been added to .hidden, and two rules for the hover event.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eCmox

Comment: @Omega I was appending a to .show:hover block , that was my mistake. Why did you add .hidden:hover to css??

Comment: @Raavi So when the mouse hovers over the links, they won't disappear.